# Send same info to multiple threads/sockets?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, pipe

I am writing a server application that simply connects a local serial port to multiple network connected clients.  I am using linux and C for the server application because the equipment for the program is a router with limited memory.

I have everything setup for multiple clients to connect and send data to the serial port using a fork() process for each connection.

My problem lies in getting data incoming on the serial port out to the multiple (varing number) client connections.  my problem lies in designing a way for each active socket to get all of the incoming data, and to only get it once.   Any help?

Comment: Are you saying that multiple network clients are reading and writing to a single common serial interface? That's what it sounds like but that's also an odd pattern.

Comment: Thats exactly it.  if it wasnt odd im sure it would be easier.  sadly the serial-in network-out is the important direction.  the other direction was easier as each thread writes to the serial port directly as needed.

Comment: I am not sure your design or requirement is right. You should be very careful with serial ports. You might use a multiplexing syscall like `poll` or `select`  instead of several threads.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a data queue (buffer) for each connected client.  Each time data comes in on the port, you post it to the back of each client's queue.  The clients then read the data from the front of their respective queues.  Since all the clients will probably read at different rates/times, this will ensure all of them get a copy of the data only once, and you won't get hung up waiting for any one client while more data comes in.  Of course, you'll need to allocate a certain amount of memory for each connected client's queue (I'm not sure how many clients you're expecting, and you did say your available memory is limited), and you need to consider what to do if a queue gets full before the client reads all of it.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you keep a list or some other reference of/to connected clients, why not just loop over that for each bit of information and send it to all of them?

Comment: thanks, thats the approach im trying currently, i was hoping there was some "built-in--pipes or similar" way of doing, i've got a large number of loops aready running.

Answer (score 0):

A thread per socket design might not be the best way to solve this. An event driven asynchronous approach should be a much better fit. However, if you must do it with threads, and given that serial ports are slow anyway, building a pipe between the thread listening to the serial port and all the threads talking to the network clients is the most practical. You could do fancy things with rwlocks to move the data, but you'll still need a way for the network threads to wait on both the socket and the data from the serial port, so you need to use file descriptors for both and something like poll.

But seriously, this would likely be much easier and would perform better without the threads. Think of it as a main loop which waits on poll which is watching the network and the serial port, determines which event occurred, and distributes data accordingly. It should be easier all around once you get the idea.

Comment: Just reread and given the environment you may not have the standard POSIX facilities, so pipes might not be an option. An alternative would be a signal that interrupted the read wait on the network socket. But assuming you have some form of poll, which should be a relatively safe assumption, I'd still just try giving up the threads entirely as I don't see what they add.

Comment: Thanks. this type of server programming is new to me so im trying to crawl my way along, and threads/fork was the first way i found to handle multiple conections, I'm tryin to get my head around this other approach you talk about, so instead of fork()'ing i would instead add the fd of the new socket to some time of array, then come back around and process each member of the array (read/write)??

Comment: You'll need an array of connections, and you'll need to understand the poll interface. Once you get that, your event loop just needs to use the provided functions for testing which FD(s) was/were raised and handle the events (it's up to you to figure out how to use those facilities to create logic to route events into handlers), of which I think you have four: connect, disconnect, receive from serial and receive from a network client.